# Const declaration causing linker error in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header, constants, linker-errors

I'm creating an openGL engine (one side for ES 1.1 and one for ES 2.0). Both of the engines currently have some constant Vertex's in them (as shown below). Unfortunately, when compiling I receive the following error:

```
 ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with the duplicate symbol being _Verticies.
```

Why is Xcode complaining about a duplicated constant value in two separate files? The files to conform to the same protocol... but for the most part that's their connection. In C++, this method works fine, but causes the noted error when translated over to Objective-C.

```
//Define the positions and colors of two triangles
const Vertex Verticies[] = { //per vertex data
    {{-0.5f, -0.866f},{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f}},
    {{0.5f, -0.866f},{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f}},
    {{0.0f, 1.0f},{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f}},
    {{-0.5f, -0.866f},{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f}},
    {{0.5f, -0.866f},{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f}},
    {{0.0f, -0.4f},{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f}},
};
```

Solution: As of now it seems that by default const values in Objective-C are subjected to the project's scope rather just the file's scope. In C++, when creating a const value, the scope is automatically limited to the file it's in. To fix this problem in Objective-C, the static tag must be used to limit the scope to that particular file. You may also use an extern tag (but that would be a bit more work).

Comment: You should really mention in your question that it works in C++ and stops working in Objective-C.

Comment: I did, it's at the end of my statement saying in C++ this method does work fine. I'll clarify on that just in case there's any confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works in C++ because in C++, a global variable with `const` is also implied to be `static`. This is not the case in C. When you change to Objective-C, which "inherits" from C, this behavior is lost and `const` symbols suddenly become `extern`.

Prefix your `const` variables with `static` to get the same behavior you had in C++.

Comment: It's confusing to use the term `static` when talking about variables as the keyword has different meanings. It's much clearer to say `const` implies "internal linkage" in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I honestly had no idea, but now I know. Fun facts!

Answer (score 3):

If the `Verticies` variable is used in only one compilation unit (file) you should declare it using the storage class specifier `static`.

This prevents the compiler from emitting an external symbol visible to the linker. In C lingo: The symbol then has internal linkage.

One of the many subtle differences between C and C++ is that `const` in C does not imply internal linkage.

Comment: `const` on file-level variables implies `static`. Unless the array was defined as an `extern const` before, it is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: That is true, my bigger question though is why does declaring this const in two different files work in C++ but not in Objective-C?

Comment: @zneak That's only true for C++ but it's not for C.

Comment: Well here's the problem then.